# Hide iframe html element until clicked button or link (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

This is my single.php

```
$id = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
$text = the_content_devturkeli('<p class="serif">Full Text &raquo;</p>'); 
$last = preg_replace('^<iframe(.*?)></iframe>^', '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showBlock(\'' . $id . '\')">Click To Watch</a> <div style="display: none;" id="' . $id . '"><embed\\1>\\2</embed><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="hideBlock(\'' . $id . '\')"> Hide</a></div>', $text);
unset($id);
echo $last;
```

I'm searching how to do this almost one month , i can not cause i dont know how to use ajax in wordpress .

I tried a lot but i dont know how to do it . When you answering this question please tell me where should i add your code (function.php or you should open ajax-xxx.js and add this)  cause many times the website doesnt work when i add code ...

---

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/H76_oByaDZk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    Game of Thrones S7 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

My code is working ,  click button then loading iframe but i want to hide my iframe an html element .

this is my single.php

```
$id = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
$text = the_content_devturkeli('<p class="serif">Full Text &raquo;</p>'); 
$last = preg_replace('^<iframe(.*?)></iframe>^', '<a href="#" onclick="showBlock(\'' . $id . '\')">Click To Watch</a> <div style="display: none;" id="' . $id . '"><embed\\1>\\2</embed><a href="#" onclick="hideBlock(\'' . $id . '\')"> Hide</a></div>', $text);
unset($id);
echo $last;
```

The video loading after click button , but i can not hide html source code

I tried a lot but i dont know how to do it . When you answering this question please tell me where should i add your code (function.php or smt) cause many times the website doesnt work when i add code . Have a good day .

Also i changed those

wp-includes/post-template.php

```
function the_content_devturkeli($more_link_text = null, $stripteaser = 0, $more_file = '') {
         $content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file);
         $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
         $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
         return $content;
}
```

And header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function showBlock(blockId) { 
    document.getElementById(blockId).style.display = "block"; 
} 
function hideBlock(blockId) { 
    document.getElementById(blockId).style.display = "none"; 
} 
</script>
```

Which part should i edit those . I want to hide html source code until clicked

this part from content not all content .

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/H76_oByaDZk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Have good day ...

Comment: simple hide the `iframe` on `document.ready` `$('iframe').hide();` once button clicked you can show like this `$('iframe').show();`

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** simple hide the `iframe` on `document.ready`

`$('iframe').hide();`

**Or :**  you can add the  style attribute `style="display:none"` to iframe in `server side` .

**2nd :** On `button click` you can show the `iframe` like this

`$('iframe').show();`